# Entity Framework Transactions and Deadlock

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework, transactions, deadlock

When SaveChanges() is called on the context, all insert/delete/update operations are executed in a single transaction. It is also possible to use DbContextTransaction for transactions. I am trying to simulate deadlock using both of these approaches. When I use DbContextTransaction, I get the deadlock exception right away but SaveChanges() alone does not throw any deadlock exceptions even after an hour. Am I doing something wrong?

Here is the code with DbContextTransaction. I try to update the first row and then the second row in the main thread. I also start another task which tries to update the second row first and then the first row.

```
        while (true)
        {
            using (var context = new SchoolDBEntities())
            {
                using (System.Data.Entity.DbContextTransaction dbTran = context.Database.BeginTransaction())
                {
                    Random r = new Random();
                    int r1 = r.Next();
                    int r2 = r.Next();

                    Student std1 = context.Students.First();
                    std1.StudentName = "test"+r1;
                    context.SaveChanges();

                    Student std2 = context.Students.Find(2);
                    std2.StudentName = "test"+r2;
                    context.SaveChanges();

                    dbTran.Commit();

                }

            }
        }
```

But when I try it with just SaveChanges() it does not generate deadlock:

```
        while (true)
        {
            using (var context = new SchoolDBEntities())
            {
                try
                {
                    Random r = new Random();
                    int r1 = r.Next();
                    int r2 = r.Next();

                    Student std1 = context.Students.First();
                    std1.StudentName = "test" + r1;
                    Student std2 = context.Students.Find(2);
                    std2.StudentName = "test" + r2;

                    context.SaveChanges();
                }
            }
        }
```

I am using SQL Profiler to trace the transactions. I even added more updates to the second approach just to make that transaction's duration equal to the DbContextTransaction case thinking it might be the reason but still no luck! When I look at the trace, I see that updates belonging to a particular transaction start only after the previous transaction is committed. What could be the reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upon further investigation, I found out that regadless of the order of changes I have made in the context, the order in which SaveChanges() method always sends update queries to the SQL Server is based on the primary key of the table. In other words, even though I try to reverse the order of update request by first changing row 2 and then row 1, SaveChanges() first executes the update query for row 1 and then for row 2. That's why I don't get a deadlock by using just SaveChanges() method. It does not reverse the order of the queries.